# Password while file deletion

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

What are the different ways of encrypting files other than zip compression with password?

I also want to get prompted for my password while permanently deleting some files, both password protected and not password protected files.

What should I do for that? I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Usually one question per post. There are many ways to encrypt on Ubuntu, both graphical and from the command line. Linux does not really password protect the way you imagine, linux uses permissions.

Comment: deleting on Linux filesystem with permissions means you can also NOT write a file since writing a file where someone deletes all of the content and then saves it is actual the same as deleting (albeit that the file still exists with 0 byes). If you want specific rules regarding deleting you can use ACL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs ).

Comment: Secondly: I myself would not bother. If you have specific users restrain them to their own /home/$USER/ (meaning: do not give them sudo permissions). Let them delete files in home. If needed make regular backups of those /homes. Don't go through hoops to prevent someone from deleting something.

Comment: if i am logged in and someone accidently deletes it then?

Comment: Then you are the one to blame. On a multi-user system the admin NEVER EVER EVER leaves his account logged in. Oh and if you do that you are missing something: preventing another user from deleting files when you are logged in as admin is impossible (admin owns the system on every level). You should start with a normal setup and lock user to their own home (as it is by default).

Comment: If you are new to encryption, I would be very careful... you wouldn't be the first to lose a lot of data because of a lost password/passphrase! Just so you know, if you lose your password, it's not like the admin can reset your password and give access to your files again. Worst case scenario, the encryption needs to be cracked... Get yourself a book and read about it first. Then you will also not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt file(s) in Ubuntu use [Private Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory) mechanism. It transparently encrypts all files that you put into the *~/Private* directory.